# Global exception handler for java spring console application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, console-application

Im working on small console application. In some places in my code i'm throwing custom RuntimeExceptions when something bad happens. What i'm looking for is a global exception handler that i can use to catch my exceptions and display proper information for user (also log them).

So my idea is to use try-catch in here:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TfsWorkReporterApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            SpringApplication.run(TfsWorkReporterApplication.class, args);
        } catch(CustomException ex){
            //Display user information.
        }
    }
}
```

But my sixth sense tells me that this isn't the proper way to do it. Any help?

Comment: try to post the error

Comment: My question is: is there any better way to do this? Any proper way for spring to handle all exceptions in one place?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using **@ControllerAdvice** but I am not sure if it will work for standalone application, for web application works, something like this

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalDefaultExceptionHandler {
   @ExceptionHandler(value = CustomException.class)
   public void defaultErrorHandler(CustomException e) {
       //handle here
   }
}
```

Comment: I will try marking my classes as @Controllers and i will test it.

Comment: Did you succeed with your exception handling? Please share your code snips.